# Any Commons all substrings function?

Tags: java, substring, apache-commons, code-reuse, apache-stringutils

I'm wondering if there's a library function (or why StringUtils in Apache Commons doesn't have it?) that for a String calculates all the substrings. 
For "abcde" it retuns "a", "ab", "b", "abc", "bc", "c", "abcd", "bcd", "cd","d", "abcde", "bcde", "cde", "de", "e".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think AndyPerfect's will work correctly. The second loop bound needs to be <= instead of just <.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPowerSet(String original) {
       ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();

       toReturn.add("");

       for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
          for (int j = i + 1; j <= original.length(); j++) {
             toReturn.add(original.substring(i, j));
          }
       }

       return toReturn;
    }
```

Note that you can remove that first add() if you don't want the empty substring included.

Comment: However, Stephen C was right with the 2^N. You need to remember the empty substring. You can look up power sets if you need more info.

Comment: No he wasn't ... his mental proof was flawed.

Comment: haven't tried it, but this discussion proves that there's room for error implementing it, and it refers to an identifiable problem (hence common?) ==> StringUtils

Comment: Yeah, after thinking it isn't 2^N. I was thinking power sets and not restricted ones. You might want to rename the method if you use it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a library function, but it would be extremely easy to just roll one youself:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllSubstrings(String s)
{
   ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++)
         toReturn.add(s.substring(i, j));
}
```

Remember though, that there will be a number of permutations equal to 1+2+3+4+...+s.length

Answer (score 0):

Sounds computational intensive. Think of all the permutations you would have with whole sentences.

That and they probably figured if somebody needed something that wasn't something needed on a regular basis.

Comment: StringUtils is not for regular-basis (String is).The point is that since it has an easy id (allSubstrings(..)) I'd expect StringUtils to have it. The same for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-261 in FileUtils.

Answer (score 0):

public static ArrayList getPowerSet(String original) {
       ArrayList toReturn = new ArrayList();

```
   toReturn.add("");

   for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j <= original.length(); j++) {
         toReturn.add(original.substring(i, j));
      }
   }

   return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPowerSet(String original) {
       ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();

       toReturn.add("");

       for (int k = 0; k < original.length(); k++) {
          for (int j = k + 1; j <= original.length(); j++) {
             toReturn.add(original.substring(k, j));
          }
       }

       return toReturn;
    }
```